# Showing two gifs using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to show a gif on my page and succeeded in showing it.

But now i want to show two gifs next to each other.
I was wondering is it possible to do so.

**CSS**

```
#loader {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1000;
 margin-left: 0%;
 margin-top: 0%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) url('../Images/loading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="loader"></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(window).load(function () {
   $('#loader').fadeOut(500);
 });
```

Now can i add one more `gif in background using url`???

I tried following but it does not seem to work

```
 #loader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) url('../Images/loading.gif') , url('../Images/ajax-loader.gif') 50% 50% ;
 }
```

Comment: u mean show GIF 1 for 10 seconds , then for other 10 seconds display GIF2 and then GIF 1 , and so on?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird displaying both simultaneously next to each other. One gif i have text 'LOADING' and other i have spinner. Want to show both.

Comment: @Richa can't you append the text `loading...` in the div itself and adjust the gif accordingly.

Comment: You can either use multiple backgrounds, or have one as an inline IMG and the other as background image.. or two separate html elements also an option.

Comment: @Jai The text Loading also has animation. So i cant simply append it as text

Comment: @Richa okay i got it now.

Comment: @Richa cant u use css3 for the text animation?

Comment: @Sweetz Ofcourse i can, but i was thinking about gifs and it use simultaneously

Comment: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the fiddle

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/TShmm/1/)

Code

```
div#loader {
background-image: url('http://www.misd.gov.sc/misdsd/Assets/programmer.gif'), url('http://www.misd.gov.sc/misdsd/Assets/programmer.gif');
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: top left, top right;
width: 385px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have an element like this:

```
<div id="loader">
   <span id='loadtxt'></span>
</div>
```

then two css classes like this:

```
#loader {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('http://i837.photobucket.com/albums/zz296/sayalie30/loading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
#loadtxt {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('http://lotyd.xtgem.com/images/bg-loading.gif') 50% 70% no-repeat;
}
```

you can adjust it as per your need.

Comment: Thanks... Let me try it out :)

Comment: @Richa oops it is overridden.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 does support multiple backgrounds (http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)
check out the examples below